# C++ Writing Hex To Process Instead Of String

Tags: c++, string, winapi, hex, cin

I'm having a problem with WriteProcessMemory where it's taking the actual string inputted and writing it to the process as an actual string instead of a hex representation when I do a \x prefix, is there another method to do this?

```
std::string HexToWrite;
std::cin >> HexToWrite; // I'm typing \x90
WriteProcessMemory(Process, Address, HexToWrite.c_str(), sizeof(HexToWrite), 0);
```

So instead of it writing the actual byte 0x90, it's writing the string instead: \x90

Comment: `\x90` doesn't mean anything special except to the compiler as a string literal. You'll need to parse it and convert the character yourself to have this done at run-time.

Comment: On a side-note, beware that `sizeof(HexToWrite)` is not the length of your string.  You should use `HexToWrite.size()` for that.

Comment: I'd say that your real problem is that you are mixing up text and binary. Don't use a string to hold an array of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

std::string is a container, not a char array.  In your WriteProcessMemory call you pass this as the size argument:

`sizeof(HexToWrite)`

This gives the size of the container, not the length of the actual string.

If you want to get the length of the string you can use:

`HexToWrite.Length()` or `strlen(HexToWrite.c_str())`

In general I wouldn't use a std::string for a byte array, I would use a regular char array:

`char* HexToWrite = "\0x90";`